# How to format a Header, Footer, and 2 Body Elements properly?

Tags: html, css

```
<style type="text/css">

    .container{
        position:center;
        margin-left:500px;
        margin-right:500px;
    }

    header {
        height:200px;
        background-color:green;
    }
    footer {
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
    }

    .body {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        height:650px;
    }

    .side {
        background-color:yellow;
        flex:0.5;
    }

    .middle {
        background-color:teal;
        flex:2;
    }
</style>    
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <header> I'm a header idiot</header>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="side"> Stuff</div>
        <div class="middle">More Stuff</div>
    </div>
    <footer>SHEEEEEEEEEET</footer>
</div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to make a webpage that is formatted similarly to this:

[image: desired layout]

The code I have currently is a very botchy, way of doing it but doesn't scale with window size and only looks good full screen relative to my screen size. What am I missing? It is supposed to be centered on the page and not have its width spread across the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.container` to this. You can use any width you like.

```
.container {
    /* position:center; */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%
}
```

```css
.container {
  /* position:center; */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%
}
header {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 650px;
}
.side {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0.5;
}
.middle {
  background-color: teal;
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>I'm a header</header>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="side">Stuff</div>
    <div class="middle">More Stuff</div>
  </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove just:

```
.container {
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-right: 500px;
}
```

from your code will solved your issue.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmodeo1w/)

And for getting output same as image(like center div). Give parent `text-align:center;`. Here body is parent so.

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Check [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmodeo1w/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
   #main{
       height:500px;
       width:100%;

}
#div1{
    width:99%;
    height:25%;
    border: 2px solid;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    top: 30px;
}
#div2{
    width:20%;
    height:60%;
    border: 2px solid;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    float:left;
}
#div3{
    width:78%;
    height:60%;
    border: 2px solid;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    float:right;
}

#div4{
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    border: 2px solid;
    float:left;

}
</style>
<body>
  <div id="main">
  <div id="div1">11
  </div>
  <div id="div2">33
  </div>
  <div id="div3">222
  </div>
<div id="div4">
test
</div>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Description:- You jsut nedd to give margin  for adjusting all layouts and need to remove (.container) Class .Below is code you can check that.

Code:-

```
 <style type="text/css">

    .body {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        height:650px;
    }



    header {
        height:200px;
        background-color:green;
        margin:20px 20px 0px 20px;
    }
    footer {
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
        margin:15px 20px 0px 20px;
    }



    .side {
        background-color:yellow;
        flex:0.5;
        margin:15px 10px 0px 20px;
    }

    .middle {
        background-color:teal;
        margin:15px 20px 0px 10px;
        flex:2;
    }







</style>    
</head>

<body>
<div >
    <header> I'm a header bitch</header>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="side"> Stuff</div>
        <div class="middle">More Stuff</div>
    </div>
    <footer>SHEEEEEEEEEET</footer>
</div>
</body>
```